# Confusion between using the EL exp tag and JSP expression tags with JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have been learning Java on my own for a while and currently learning the 5 cat-tags of JSTL. To my understanding JSTL was made to make things easier from HTML and Java in JSP. I find that it makes things more weird/complicated.

My biggest confusion is when to use `${el}` or `<%=exp %>` with JSTL tags because both of these are heavily used in JSTL to set values, get values/objects, print them and so on. I just don't understand when to use which and why. A few simple examples are below. Can someone please tell me which to use when is JSTL and why?

```
<c:set var="newArr" value="<%=myArray %>"></c:set>

 <c:set target="${student }" property="name" value="Sarah"></c:set>

<c:out value="${anyName }"></c:out>
```

Comment: JSP  expression tags  are for scripting variables.  EL is for scoped variables.

Comment: Just never use `<% ... %>` anymore. That's all.

Comment: I dont use scriplets at all... my confusion is experienced developers are using el tag or jsp expression with jstl and I can't seem to understand when and why at times they use el inside jstl and than randomly say not to use el and use expression instead.  Like in my example above to get an array expression is used instead of el